# Solr field depth

Tags: solr, indexing

How would one set up Solr such that we have "child" node fields?
For example, for this doc, there exists 2 cars, but each car has a subset of colors.

For example:

```
<doc>
  <field name = "make"> Toyota </field>
     <field name = "car"> Camri </field>
        <field name = "color"> Silver </field>
        <field name = "color"> Red </field>
     <field name = "car"> Corolla </field>
        <field name = "color"> Blue </field>
        <field name = "color"> Red </field>
<doc>
```

How would one go about getting these relationships indexed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general practice is to denormalize the database as Solr works with a plain schema. For example, you can make a multi-valued field and put these values into it:

- Camri/Silver
- Camri/Red
- Corolla/Blue
- Corolla/Red